# Can a South Korean PhD student completing their military service as part of their Ph.D. degree do an internship in the United States?

Tags: usa, internship, south-korea

Can a PhD student in South Korea, South Korean citizen and completing their military service as part of their Ph.D. degree do an internship in the United States?

---

Background: In South Korea, PhD programs typically last five years. The first two years are dedicated to coursework, then the last three years are focused on research.

During the last three years of research, most of the top university students who are South Korean citizens are serving alternative military service (participating 3 years research program in the dedicated research facility). Usually, they can stay in their lab in the university because the government allows the university some portion of this program. As a result, they can complete their military service while pursuing their Ph.D. degree. But it is unclear to me whether these students can come to the US for an internship during  their PhD (during the last three years focusing on research).